# Remove duplicate array data using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i want to remove the data from the array when there profile_id duplicate.
this is my array

```
 $response[0]['profile_id'] = 100; 
 $response[0]['profile_name'] = 'deepu';
 $response[0]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpu';

 $response[1]['profile_id'] = 101; 
 $response[1]['profile_name'] = 'deepu';
 $response[1]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpu';


 $response[2]['profile_id'] = 100; 
 $response[2]['profile_name'] = 'deepu';
 $response[2]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpusdvsdvsdvsdvsdv';

 $response[3]['profile_id'] = 102; 
 $response[3]['profile_name'] = 'desdvsdvepu';
 $response[3]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpusdvsdvsdvsdvsdsdvsdvv';


 $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $response)));
```

i want this output

```
   $response[0]['profile_id'] = 100; 
   $response[0]['profile_name'] = 'deepu';
   $response[0]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpu';

   $response[1]['profile_id'] = 101; 
   $response[1]['profile_name'] = 'deepu';
   $response[1]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpu';

   $response[3]['profile_id'] = 102; 
   $response[3]['profile_name'] = 'desdvsdvepu';
   $response[3]['address'] = 'deesdvsdvsdvpusdvsdvsdvsdvsdsdvsdvv';
```

But I can't get this. If anyone knows about this please help me.

Comment: It would be better if you can just post the `print_r()` output of your existing array and the expected result. (You can make the output formatting prettier with this statement: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($your_array, TRUE).'</pre>';`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the php-function: [array_unique](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php)

Or manual:

```
$ids = array();

foreach($response as $key => $entry){
  if(in_array($entry['profile_id'], $ids)){
    unset($response[$key]);
  }else{
    $ids[] = $entry['profile_id'];
  }
}
```

Comment: THis is multidimensioanal array.

Comment: Thx @u_mulder didn't used this function before. Therefor i said "try" :) - So, array_unique should be no option. But i added a foreach-solution. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_arr = array_reduce($response, function($t, $v) {
    $profile_id = $v['profile_id'];
    if (!isset($t[$profile_id]))
        $t[$profile_id] = $v;
    return $t;
}, array());
$new_arr = array_values($new_arr); // to get indexes back to 0, 1, 2...
```